# Filtering rows which meet a condition per group (leave all the group if condition is satisfied) in R using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Does anyone have an idea how to filter rows based on condition per group?
[image]

The first table in the left is the data I have right now and the one in the right is the desired result. I want to leave all rows with those ID numbers, where year is equal to 2009 (even just one row has the certain value, I want to leave others too). I tried the code:

```
filtered <- dt %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Year == 2009))
```

But it does not work. Could it be done using data.table? That would be the best solution.
Thanks in advance!

Data:

```
data1=data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
             "Year"=c(2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2009,2010,2011,2014,2015,2016,2017),
             "Price" = c(4,5,7,3,5,7,9,6,7,8,5,3,5,7,8,9,3,5))
```

Comment: The dplyr solution would be `semi_join(data1, filter(data1, Year == 2009), by = "ID")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve your problem as follow:

```
# method 1: using data.table

library(data.table)

setDT(data1)[ID %in% ID[Year==2009],]   
# or
data1[, if(2009 %in% Year) .SD, by=ID]

      ID  Year Price
1:     1  2009     4
2:     1  2010     5
3:     1  2011     7
4:     1  2012     3
5:     1  2013     5
6:     1  2014     7
7:     3  2009     3
8:     3  2010     5
9:     3  2011     7


# method 2: using dplyr

library(dplyr)

data1 %>%
  filter(ID %in% ID[Year==2009])

  ID Year Price
1  1 2009     4
2  1 2010     5
3  1 2011     7
4  1 2012     3
5  1 2013     5
6  1 2014     7
7  3 2009     3
8  3 2010     5
9  3 2011     7
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                    "Year"=c(2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2009,2010,2011,2014,2015,2016,2017),
                    "Price" = c(4,5,7,3,5,7,9,6,7,8,5,3,5,7,8,9,3,5))

setDT(dt)[, .SD[any(Year == 2009)], by = ID]
#>    ID Year Price
#> 1:  1 2009     4
#> 2:  1 2010     5
#> 3:  1 2011     7
#> 4:  1 2012     3
#> 5:  1 2013     5
#> 6:  1 2014     7
#> 7:  3 2009     3
#> 8:  3 2010     5
#> 9:  3 2011     7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>